# Cannot capture image of Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vhd

I think the [official Azure instructions on how to capture a VM image](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/) must be either incorrect or incomplete. I've run a variety of tests myself (detailed below) and more than two dozen people have complained on the page that the instructions don't work and/or damage their VM's. Surely something is missing from the instructions because people must be able to capture images from Azure VM's.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/

The instructions on the page are pretty simple:

- Remote Desktop into your Azure VM
- Open an administrator command window
- Run sysprep with the indicated settings (Out-Of-Box-Experience, Generalize, Shutdown)
- Hit OK
- Wait for the system to shut the VM down
- Click capture in the portal.

It sounds simple but the VM never actually shuts down so you can't actually click the capure button. If you manually shutdown the instance, even after waiting many hours, the resulting image fails to work and the original vhd is destroyed in the process.

Can anyone confirm you are able to capture a running Azure instance using either this workflow or some other workflow? If so, can you tell me what you're doing differently from what I'm doing?

Details - The tests I've run are as follows:

**TEST 1 - Win2k8 R2 on Small instance**

- Launch a small instance of Win2k8 R2 in the US West region
- Remote desktop into the image
- Run sysprep with OOBE,generalize,shutdown
- Azure dashboard shows all CPU activity completed after 15min of sysprep, device is idle, steady state is 0.41% cpu
- Wait several hours (>2.5 hours as of this writing on this instance, >12 hours on other tests)
- Azure VM is still running, capture button for the instance is unavailable in portal

**TEST 2 - Win2k8 R2 on Large instance**

- same steps as Test 1 but on Large instance
- same results except steady state CPU utilization is 0.08% after 15 minutes

**TEST 3 - Win2k12 Data Center Edition on small instance**

- same steps as Test 1 but run Win2k12 Data Center
- same result as Test 1 except steady state CPU utilization is 4.2%

**TEST 4 - Win2k8 R2 on Small instance with Windows update**

- same steps as Test 1 but run Windows Update repeatedly until no more updates available before running sysprep
- same results as Test 1

**TEST 5 - Win2k8 R2 on Small instance with Visual Studio 2012 Update 3**

- same steps as Test 1 but install VS2012 Ultimate and VS2012 Update 3 before running sysprep
- same results as Test 1

**TEST 6 - Win2k8 R2 on Large instance with fully configured IIS server**

- provision our standard server configuation (IIS, .NET 4.5) on a large instance
- run our standard web service tests
- run sysprep with OOBE,generalize,shutdown
- wait 4 hours, allowing sysprep to run
- use portal to shutdown instance
- use portal to capture instance
- generated image doesn't work (provisioning machines with it times out after a couple hours)
- original VHD doesn't work (can't remote desktop into instance created with the VHD)

**TEST 7 - Win2k8 R2 on Large instance with fully configured IIS server**

- same as test 6 except wait 12 hours allowing sysprep to run
- as of this writing (12+ hours) the VM still hasn't shut down

Comment: The guide you refer to caused me massive problems! I wish I'd read the comments before following these steps. Took forever to wind down (as you mention) and then lost admin access, so had to port the disk to a new VM and reconfigure the OS. This was on a live service as well.. I wrongly assumed it would be a 5 min operation! This process works providing you create another admin account 1st or are prepared to lose the original VM.

Comment: @QF_Developer - any chance you can post a workflow that starts with "launch a small Win2k8 R2 image on azure and ..." and gives some hint of how long it takes for the process to complete so the rest of us can give it a try? That's definitely an answer I'd upvote.

Comment: I'm a content publishing manager at MS. A writer on my team is responsible for the content linked above. We've seen the comments on the page and here. We'll fix the article at the next available opportunity. Related issue detailed on the Windows Azure Support forum: [Image capture issue / VM unexpectedly started after guest-initiated shutdown](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/fafb9ee6-1e57-46ba-8440-27467ad986cf/image-capture-issue-vm-unexpectedly-started-after-guestinitiated-shutdown). Worth reading. Don, so sorry you lost your valuable time and uptime.

Comment: Unfortunately, even the revised instructions you linked to (i.e. which recommend selecting "quit" in sysprep rather than "shutdown") have left me in a state of limbo, as I was disconnected from the VM whilst sysprep was running and now I can't reconnect via RDP. I followed all the instructions to the letter.

Comment: Success! My previous comment related to a Windows Server 2012 VM. I've since tried the process on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM and thankfully it works and I can now create VMs from my captured image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make one simple change to your workflow: during sysprep, choose to Quit instead of shutdown. This completes the sysprep process but then just exits the sysprep app.

**tl;dr: run the following on the command line:**

```
c:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /generalize /oobe /quit
```

At this point, you can simply select your running VM in the portal and shut it down (which only takes a few moments). You can then view it, which will be shown as stopped (deallocated). At that point, create the image as described in the tutorial you pointed to. You'll give it a name (e.g. "my specialized image"), click the checkbox stating it's been sysprepped, and click Ok. Your image is created, your original vhd is removed (as now you have a generic version of it), the image is registered in your subscription as a choosable image in the gallery (this takes a few minutes), and you're done.

At this point, create a new image from gallery. View **MY IMAGES** - you'll see your brand new image listed (you may have to wait a minute or so before attempting this - it might not appear *immediately* in the list).

Now just give it a username and password, and you should be all set.

**Note**: If you're worried about losing your VM in this step (e.g. something goes wrong), you can always make a copy of your vhd first. You'll need to use PowerShell (or the cross-platform Node-based command line tool), both downloadable from the windowsazure.com [downloads](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/#cmd-line-tools) page. You can then copy the vhd to a brand new blob, which essentially makes a backup for you. Should something go wrong, you can either use the backed-up image as the basis for a new virtual machine (which won't be sysprepped yet), or make a copy of it (and so on). To do this, you'll need the url to the vhd, which is displayed in the **Disks** section of the **Dashboard** page of your running VM.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Since your bio says you're on the Azure team at MSFT, could you PLEASE log a bug on this page for us? I personally lost almost 20 working hours on this issue and our site was down for 30 hours as a result of it. There are more than two dozen complaints about that page, many of which talk about lost drives and servers, and those complaints have been coming in steadily for an entire year with no response from anyone on the Azure doc team. Those instructions are a HUGE problem for your customers. Please please please try to get someone to fix it.

Comment: I'm not on the core Azure team. That said, I'll be happy to point the appropriate team to this. It could be that those instructions work (or *worked*) just fine at some point (and perhaps still do depending on circumstances).